# Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, headset

Google obviously are introducing more and more protection for their internal broadcasts on JB or 4.1 and above. This was working fine on 4.0? Do you know if there is a way to send a new broadcast, maybe using sendOrderedBroadcast with a permission?

Which one?

Comment: Is this for attempting to answer a call? I seem to have it working on JellyBean despite one of the broadcasts being restricted.

Comment: Yes, for the incoming  calls. I will see if it works, but is throwing this exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is now a protected broadcast only system uid can send.

See: `android/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />`